# What is the optimal hardware requirements for tableau server?

Tags: mysql, reporting, tableau-api, dashboard

For testing purposes Tableau says 4 cores, 8 GB RAM and 15 GB disk space.
But recommended one says 8 physical cores, 32 GB RAM and 50 GB disk space.

Now I am stuck as 2nd configuration seems to be an overkill. I don't have heavy requirements. How should I decide on cores and RAM?

> I shall be connecting Tableau to MySQL for real time dashboards

Comment: You will probably need to experiment. A lot depends on the number of simultaneous users and whether the dashboards are complex and/or dense with data. More memory often pays off. There is a free tool called TabJolt you can use for synthesizing workload for performance testing.

Answer (score 2):

> "Tableau Server will not install if your computer does not meet the
>   minimum requirements"

See the absolute minimum requirements here: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#server_hardware_min.htm

*The minimum configuration recommended for **production** usage of Tableau Server is based on these hardware specifications:*

- Single computer
- 64-bit processor
- 8 physical cores, 2.0 GHz or higher CPU
- 32 GB system memory
- 50 GB minimum free disk space

Read more here: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#requ.htm

Also, if you don't want to supply your own physical hardware you can always install on a VM. Check out the Tableau Server Bring-Your-Own-License program on [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00W2SU9U4/)